# Creating a surface with pygame but when I run program, nothing showing

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a menu for a chess game. Since I cannot create multiple pygame windows, I am attempting to create a surface on top of my game. However, when I click my trigger key to show the menu, nothing happens.

Here is the main file of my code:

```
import pygame as p
import ChessEngine
import os
from tkinter import *
import time


WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))

    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False
    animate = False
    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []
    gameOver = False
    CheckV = False
    sidebar = False
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if not gameOver:
                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                    col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                    row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                    if sqSelected == (row, col):
                        sqSelected = ()
                        playerClicks = []
                    else:
                        sqSelected = (row, col)
                        playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                    if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                        move = ChessEngine.Move(
                            playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                        for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                            if move == validMoves[i]:
                                gs.makeMove(validMoves[i])
                                moveMade = True
                                animate = True
                                sqSelected = ()
                                playerClicks = []
                        if not moveMade:
                            playerClicks = [sqSelected]

            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True
                    animate = False
                    checkMate = False
                    staleMate = False
                    gameOver = False
                if e.key == p.K_r:
                    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
                    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                    moveMade = False
                    animate = False
                    checkMate = False
                    staleMate = False
                    gameOver = False
                if e.key == p.K_s and sidebar == False:  # show sidebar
                    print('show sidebar')
                    b = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
                    b.set_alpha(255)
                    b.fill(p.Color('blue'))
                    screen.blit(b, (HEIGHT, WIDTH))
                    sidebar = True
                elif e.key == p.K_s and sidebar == True:  # show board
                    `print('hide sidebar')`
                    sidebar = False

        if moveMade:
            if animate:
                animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()

            if gs.inCheck():
                CheckV = True

            if CheckV == True:
                CheckV = False
                os.system("say 'check'")

            moveMade = False
            animate = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)

        if gs.checkMate:
            gameOver = True
            if gs.whitetoMove:
                drawText(screen, ' Black wins by Checkmate')
            else:
                drawText(screen, ' White wins by Checkmate')

        elif gs.staleMate:
            gameOver = True
            drawText(screen, 'Stalemate')
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whitetoMove else 'b'):
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)
            s.fill(p.Color('blue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE))
            s.fill(p.Color('yellow'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (SQ_SIZE*move.endCol, SQ_SIZE*move.endRow))


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 10
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        p.event.pump()
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount,
                move.startCol + dC*frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol*SQ_SIZE,
                           move.endRow*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(
            c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


def drawText(screen, text):
    font = p.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 32, True, False)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0, p.Color('Gray'))
    textLocation = p.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT).move(
        WIDTH/2 - textObject.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - textObject.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0,  p.Color("Black"))
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation.move(2, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The menu portion is this bit:

```
if e.key == p.K_s and sidebar == False:  # show sidebar
                    print('show sidebar')
                    b = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
                    b.set_alpha(255)
                    b.fill(p.Color('blue'))
                    screen.blit(b, (HEIGHT, WIDTH))
                    sidebar = True
                elif e.key == p.K_s and sidebar == True:  # show board
                    `print('hide sidebar')`
                    sidebar = False
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen.blit(b, (HEIGHT, WIDTH))
```

This bit of code places the top left corner of Surface "b" on the screen at the coordinates of the lower right corner of the screen. This means that the Surface is placed, but it isn't visible because it is entirely "offscreen."

Also!

```
b.set_alpha(255)
```

Is unnecessary, since fully opaque is the default for a Surface. No need to manually set it.

Comment: I have changed it to
```screen.blit(b, (HEIGHT-220, WIDTH-220))``` but its making no difference at all...

Comment: It looks like you are then drawing your game state over the menu, so you don't see it.